# Polymer data-binding not updated on array mutation

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I noticed that template/data-binding in Polymer doesn't seem to reflect when a array property is mutated (i.e. `push()`). Sample code below:

```html
<body>
  <dom-module id="my-element">
    <template>
      <pre>
[my-element]
myArray: [[jsonStringify(myArray)]]
      </pre>
    </template>
  </dom-module>

  <my-element id="elm"></my-element>
  <button onclick="pushArray()">pushArray</button>
  <button onclick="setArray()">setArray</button>

  <script>
    (function registerElements() {
      Polymer({
        is: 'my-element',

        properties: {
          myArray: {
            type: Array,
            value: function () {
              return [];
            }
          }
        },

        pushArray: function(value) {
          this.push('myArray', {id: value});
        },

        setArray: function(value) {
          this.set('myArray', [{id: value}]);
        },

        jsonStringify: function(obj) {
          return JSON.stringify(obj);
        }
      });
    })();

    function pushArray () {
      var elm = document.querySelector('#elm');
      elm.pushArray('Push');
    }

    function setArray () {
      var elm = document.querySelector('#elm');
      elm.setArray('Set');
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Whenever I click the `pushArray` button, an item "Push" should be added in `myArray`, but it wasn't reflected in the template `[[jsonStringify(myArray)]]`. is this an expected behavior? Anyway to work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Array change observer is a bit tricky. In your code, by using `myArray`, you implicitly observe (only) the reference for the (whole) array, which only changes when you run `setArray`.

In order to overcome this, you must also use a deep observer, namely `myArray.*`. The correct code for your `dom-module` is therefore the following:

```
  <dom-module id="my-element">
    <template>
      <pre>
        [my-element]
        myArray: [[jsonStringify(myArray, myArray.*)]]
      </pre>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
```

Live demo: http://jsbin.com/yulivuwufu/1/edit?html,css,output

No other code changes are necessary.

Comment: I thought by using the Polymer's `push()` (instead of JS native `push()`) already made `myArray` change observable? Did I missed out something?

Comment: You didn't miss anything. You *do* need to use Polymer's `push()`, otherwise even my solution won't work. But as I have said, array mutations don't trigger the change on the array object itself, so you have to use other options: a deep observer `myArray.*`, array length observer `myArray.length`, or a splices observer `myArray.splices`.